# How to fix an attribution error when converting a python script to an .exe using Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pyinstaller, attribution

Relative Linux noob here. Just trying to convert a python code into an .exe

When I run pyinstaller (1st time since install) it creates the dist file, but it is empty.

Error looks like this:

```
48 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5+498e6ee058
48 INFO: Python: 3.9.9
51 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.14.0-kali4-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.33
61 INFO: wrote /home/kali/Py_Projects/turtles.spec
68 INFO: UPX is available.
70 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/kali/Py_Projects', '/home/kali/Py_Projects']
70 INFO: checking Analysis
70 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
70 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
77 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
79 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3395 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
8396 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
8443 INFO: Caching module hooks...
8447 INFO: Analyzing /home/kali/Py_Projects/turtles.py
8577 INFO: Loading module hooks...
8577 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
8579 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
8587 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
8588 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
8589 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
8589 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
8712 INFO: checking Tree
8712 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
8712 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
8719 INFO: checking Tree
8719 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
8719 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
8722 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
8898 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
8975 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
9004 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
9008 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
9014 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
9034 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
9823 INFO: Looking for eggs
9823 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.5+498e6ee058', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/kali/Py_Projects/turtles.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['turtles.py'],
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 575, in assemble
    self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 666, in _check_python_library
    python_lib = bindepend.get_python_library_path()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 914, in get_python_library_path
    python_libname = findLibrary(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 778, in findLibrary
    utils.load_ldconfig_cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/utils.py", line 375, in load_ldconfig_cache
    path = m.groups()[-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

It seems a fairly straight forward process, I have updated both python and pyinstaller...not sure where to go next. Any help?

Comment: Why do you intend to create an exe in Linux?

Comment: it seems I should be able to create it in linux and then copy it out for use on a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by going here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/develop

Downloading the ZIP and replacing the PyInstaller directory from here: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/